# EF query taking orders of magnitude longer to count than to fully list

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I have a query inside EF which is performing an intersection between two sets and counting the number of rows returned. Its not a terribly complicated query and the generated SQL is simple.

This query however is taking far too long to execute using EF.

- This query takes no time to run in SSMS (20ms) but when I run it via EF it takes approx 800ms even though the underlying SQL is identical. This sugguests to me the issue is not indices.
- I have looked at the generated SQL in both Sql Profiler and EF Profiler and the generated SQL is as expected.
- If I run the query text via EF with `.SqlQuery<int>` it also executes
  in approx 20ms.
- Order of execution is not the issue whichever order i run `.SqlQuery<int>` and the actual EF query in reproduces the EF perf problem (ie it doesn't appear to be a SQL query caching issue)
- If I remove the count from the query (eg use `.ToArray().Count()`) it executes in approx 20ms (however this isn't really a workable solution if the intersection is sufficiently large)
- Query plan seems sensible, its all in the indices and it performs fine outside of EF

**Does anyone know anything which could cause this behavior, or any additional things I could try to diagnose it?**

**Edit:**

I did a little more playing around with the query and noticed that the generated SQL is a little different in EF Profiler to SQL Profiler, EF Profiler tidies it a little by removing the `exec sp_executesql` and parametrisation from the query. When I replicated this in my code based query I was able to reproduce the poor performance of the EF query (which is good). It still however ran fast in any situation using SSMS.

My assumption was that issues with Parameter Sniffing were isolated to the first execution of an identical query. However further reading has proved this assumption invalid. I was able to prove that this is caused by parameter sniffing (as @MitchWheat suggested) by adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of the `exec sp_executesql` string. This made it execute in a reasonable time frame.

I'm still not sure how to resolve this issue with EF but at least I know what it is.

### Supporting Gumph

**EF Query**

```
var query = (from c in ctx.RuleCurrentMembershipCache
             where c.RuleId == baseRule
             where c.Direction == Direction.In
             select c.Key)
                .Distinct()
                .Intersect((from c in ctx.RuleCurrentMembershipCache
                           where c.RuleId == ruleId
                           where c.Direction == Direction.In
                            select c.Key).Distinct());

query.ToArray().Count();//fast
query.Count();//slow
```

**Generated SQL**

```
SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM (
        SELECT [Distinct1].[Key] AS [Key]
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT [Extent1].[Key] AS [Key]
            FROM   [RuleCurrentMembershipCache] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[RuleId] = 'c0cdd83d-0cad-430d-bb6a-7abdbf115856' /* @p__linq__0 */)
              AND (1 = CAST([Extent1].[Direction] AS int)
                
                   )
            ) AS [Distinct1]
        INTERSECT
        SELECT [Distinct2].[Key] AS [Key]
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT [Extent2].[Key] AS [Key]
            FROM  [RuleCurrentMembershipCache] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent2].[RuleId] = '6d97cf92-8a57-4de2-8756-0abe6977eb7d' /* @p__linq__1 */)
              AND (1 = CAST([Extent2].[Direction] AS int))
        ) AS [Distinct2]
    ) AS [Intersect1]
) AS [GroupBy1]
```

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE [RuleCurrentMembershipCache](
    [RuleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Key] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [Direction] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RuleCurrentMembershipCache] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RuleId] ASC,
    [Key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_RuleId] ON [RuleCurrentMembershipCache]
(
    [RuleId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Direction],
    [Key]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: "This query takes no time to run in SSMS (20ms) but when I run it via EF it takes approx 800ms even though the underlying SQL is identical. This sugguests to me the issue is not indices." - often a symptom of parameter sniffing...

Comment: @MitchWheat I thought it might be something weird like that. To isolate it I tried priming the system by manually executing the SQL twice, once with a raw SQL command and then with the EF query. My understanding is that param sniffing should make the first slow. However whichever way I order them its always the EF one which is slow. Is there anything else i should try?

Comment: @MitchWheat I did a bit more research and you are totally right, it is being caused by parameter sniffing. If you post that I will accept it (as this was a why question). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I wonder if reformatting the query using contains pr any rather than intersect would help with the performance, and avoid parameter sniffing altogether

Comment: @TheVedge Its actually susceptible to exactly the same problem, however that change did allow me to shave a little time of my query because of http://www.execsql.com/post/intersectexcept-versus-innot-in (which I didnt realise) so thanks :)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor no problems. I would also argue that the distinct in your second statement is not required, since you're never returning that dataset anyway.

Comment: @TheVedge yeah I took the distinct's out in the contains based query and just did one at the end :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "This query takes no time to run in SSMS (20ms) but when I run it via
>   EF it takes approx 800ms even though the underlying SQL is identical.
>   This sugguests to me the issue is not indices."

This is often a symptom of parameter sniffing.  SSMS sets options on the connection that cause queries when executed to be recompiled (hence the always short execution time from SSMS).

The canonical reference: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)